# Why do labels disappear in ASP.NET charting?

Tags: asp.net, charts

Chart1 shows all the labels, but once I add the 10th item, half of the labels disappear.

First the markup:

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="700" Height="600">
        <series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Bar" />
        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" />
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>

    <asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" Width="700" Height="600">
        <series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Bar" />
        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"/>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

And we add some data...

```
    Dim labels As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    labels.Add("1 thing", 24655)
    labels.Add("2 thing", 11355)
    labels.Add("3 thing", 6890)
    labels.Add("4 thing", 5815)
    labels.Add("5 thing", 5155)
    labels.Add("6 thing", 4160)
    labels.Add("7 thing", 2430)
    labels.Add("8 thing", 2055)
    labels.Add("9 thing", 1545)


    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.DataBindXY(labels, "Key", labels, "Value")
    Chart1.DataBind()

    labels.Add("10 thing", 1530)

    Chart2.Series("Series1").Points.DataBindXY(labels, "Key", labels, "Value")
    Chart2.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had to set the interval of the axis as in

```
Chart2.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Interval = 1
```

Comment: +1 I wish I could give you more as this was a great spot! this was driving me insane!!