# Cannot change label interval on asp:chart

Tags: charts, controls, label

The particular problem is one that have been asked before. I've got an asp:chart control and it's not showing all my labels on the X axis. Same question as:
[Why do labels disappear in ASP.NET charting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808363/why-do-labels-disappear-in-asp-net-charting)

However the answer (interval=1 on X axis) does nothing on my control. And furthermore, I'm wondering if I've got some wrong settings, because a lot of things does nothing when I try to change them, for example LabelAutoFitStyle setting doesn't effect anything on my chart.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Chart ID="SalesChart" Width="500" Height="400" ImageStorageMode="UseHttpHandler" EnableViewState="False" runat="server" ImageType="Png">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series ChartType="Column" Name="StatsSeries" XAxisType="Secondary" ToolTip="#VALX: #VALY{C0}" label="#VALY{C0}" LabelBorderColor="Gray" LabelBackColor="#FFF6AA">
                <Points>
                </Points>
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Area3DStyle-Enable3D="true" Name="StatsChartArea" Area3DStyle-PointGapDepth="0" Area3DStyle-Rotation="20" Area3DStyle-PointDepth="60" Area3DStyle-Inclination="20">
                <AxisX LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="10" Interval="1">
                    <MajorGrid Interval="1" />
                    <MinorGrid />
                    <LabelStyle Interval="1" />
                </AxisX>
                <AxisY>
                    <LabelStyle Format='{C0}' />
                    <MinorGrid Enabled="True" LineColor="Gray" />
                </AxisY>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

code behind (I've hidden a lot of code here that is not relevant):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Here I get chart data


            //Set everything up
            if (statsDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                SetChartData(statsDataTable);
                SetChartGridResolution();
                SetChartBarColors();
            }
        }
    }


    private void SetChartData(DataTable statsDataTable)
    {
        ArrayList xValues = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList yValues = new ArrayList();

        // I populate the lists with values, and then bind it below


        SalesChart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the intervals on the grid, based on the highest value.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetChartGridResolution()
    {
        if (SalesChart.Series[0].Points.FindMaxByValue().YValues[0] > 2000000)
        {
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 1000000;
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 1000000;
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Interval = 1000000;
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 500000;

        }
        else if (SalesChart.Series[0].Points.FindMaxByValue().YValues[0] > 1000000)
        {
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 200000;
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 200000;
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Interval = 200000;
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 100000;
        }
        else
        {
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 100000;
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 100000;
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Interval = 100000;
            SalesChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 50000;
        }
    }

    private void SetChartBarColors()
    {
        System.Drawing.Color color1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#007dc3");
        System.Drawing.Color color2 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#539dc8");

        for (int i = 0; i < SalesChart.Series[0].Points.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                SalesChart.Series[0].Points[i].Color = color1;
            else
                SalesChart.Series[0].Points[i].Color = color2;
        }
    }
```

I'd be great if you could give me a clue!

Regards Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it! This problem has cost me several hours, trying to solve various problems. I hope someone can be spared that by reading this.

It was all because of XAxisType="Secondary", when this is selected (to use the upper x-line instead of the lower) all configuration on the x-axis must be set on  instead of . This was causing a lot of things to "not work" for me...